# InvalidCastException:Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
Player.OnPhotonSerializeView (Photon.Pun.PhotonStream stream, Photon.Pun.PhotonMessageInfo info) (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:95)
Photon.Pun.PhotonView.DeserializeComponent (UnityEngine.Component component, Photon.Pun.PhotonStream stream, Photon.Pun.PhotonMessageInfo info) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonView.cs:544)
Photon.Pun.PhotonView.DeserializeView (Photon.Pun.PhotonStream stream, Photon.Pun.PhotonMessageInfo info) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonView.cs:534)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork.OnSerializeRead (System.Object[] data, Photon.Realtime.Player sender, System.Int32 networkTime, System.Int16 correctPrefix) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetworkPart.cs:1863)
Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork.OnEvent (ExitGames.Client.Photon.EventData photonEvent) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetworkPart.cs:2234)
Photon.Realtime.LoadBalancingClient.OnEvent (ExitGames.Client.Photon.EventData photonEvent) (at Assets/Photon/PhotonRealtime/Code/LoadBalancingClient.cs:3362)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.PeerBase.DeserializeMessageAndCallback (ExitGames.Client.Photon.StreamBuffer stream) (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/PeerBase.cs:904)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.EnetPeer.DispatchIncomingCommands () (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/EnetPeer.cs:577)
ExitGames.Client.Photon.PhotonPeer.DispatchIncomingCommands () (at D:/Dev/Work/photon-dotnet-sdk/PhotonDotNet/PhotonPeer.cs:1771)
Photon.Pun.PhotonHandler.Dispatch () (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonHandler.cs:232)
Rethrow as AggregateException: Caught 1 exception(s) in methods called by DispatchIncomingCommands(). Rethrowing first only (see above). (Specified cast is not valid.)
Photon.Pun.PhotonHandler.Dispatch () (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonHandler.cs:250)
Photon.Pun.PhotonHandler.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonHandler.cs:152)

```
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks,IPunObservable
{
    public GameObject objCircle;

public float spin_speed;

public float speed;
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public GameManager manager;

public PhotonView PV;
Vector3 curPos;
private void Start()
{
    manager =GameObject.Find("GameManager").GetComponent<GameManager>();
    PV = GetComponent<PhotonView>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (manager.FinishedCountDown&&PV.IsMine)
    {
        //KeyboardControl();
        Move();
    }
    else if ((transform.position - curPos).sqrMagnitude >= 10) transform.position = curPos;
    else transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, curPos, Time.deltaTime * 10);
    Spin();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    
}

void Move()
{
    Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;

    dir.x = Input.acceleration.x;
    dir.y = Input.acceleration.y;

    if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
    {
        dir.Normalize();
    }
    dir *= Time.deltaTime;

    rb.velocity = new Vector2(dir.x * speed, dir.y * speed);
}


void KeyboardControl()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector2 movement = new Vector2(moveHorizontal, moveVertical);

    rb.velocity = movement * speed*2 * Time.deltaTime;

}

void Spin()
{
    objCircle.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, -spin_speed * Time.deltaTime));
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision != null)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "SafeZone")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}

public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
{
    if (stream.IsWriting)
    {
        stream.SendNext(transform.position);
    }
    else
    {
        curPos = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();
    }
}
```

}
this is my code, and I got a problem like this. How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and tell us where exactly your cast error happens? Instead of just copying the whole stacktrace and code into your question

Comment: I would say something is wrong with this line `curPos = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();`

Comment: Exactly. Do you know why the problem arises?

Comment: Can you try this? https://forum.unity.com/threads/specified-cast-is-not-valid-onphotonserializeview.1085312/#post-8573222 ... also in general have you tried debugging and see what value/type `stream.ReceiveNext` returns exactly?

Comment: in general `Destroy(gameObject);` afaik is quite dangerous ... even further you don't check there whether this object is the actual instance or only the synchronized one (who has authority?) .. you should probably rather use `PhotonNetwork.Destroy` and make sure to go through the correct authority route

Comment: also what speaks against using the normal `PhotonTransformView` / `PhotonRigidbody2DView` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly:

```
public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        if (stream.IsWriting)
        {
            stream.SendNext(transform.position);
        }
        else
        {
            curPos = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();
                      ^^^^^^^
        }
    }
```

this part is the source of the problem. You have to be sure that `stream.ReceiveNext()` returns an object that is or is derived from Vector3 to convert it into Vector3 implicitly; otherwise, cast it by some other means.

Comment: since `transform.position` **is** a `Vector3` though and the only thing written to the stream I would, just as OP, also expect this to return a `Vector3` when reading

Comment: I am not a Unity expert but I could suggest debugging the code without casting it first. According to documentation (https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/current/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_stream.html#a238ff231a903ec20eae4ad857b90380d)  it might as well return null. So, given that it might return null and Vector3 is a struct that can not assign null, you can find a clue to the solution there.